# How do I get a table from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an assignment for school: I need to make a user database.

First I need to know how to get information from tables in my database.
Then I need to write usernames to the database.

Let's start with the first one:

I am working with MAMP.
I got this sample from my teacher, I added some echos in there.

```
< ?php

$dbhost  = 'localhost';    // Unlikely to require changing
$dbname  = 'chrisdb';        // Modify these...
$dbuser  = 'root';        // ...variables according
$dbpass  = 'root';        // ...to your installation

$db_server=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
echo("1");
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
echo("2");
mysql_select_db($dbname)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
echo("3");

?>
```

All the echos gets printed. Does that mean I have access to the server?
How do I access a table in the db and get the value of it?

And how do I write to the database?

I am not in search for the best possible code, more like the simplest possible code.
I appreciate all help you can give me. If you do help, will you please explain what your code means?

Comment: Look up how to query the database.

Comment: The interwebz is full with such basic examples, are you sure google didn't get you _anything_??

Comment: As I said, I have been on this for six hours, it is hard to google something when you have no clue of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ckrill: It sounds like you're at such a basic level that you should Google "PHP PDO MySQL tutorial". This is definitively not a real question and I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write to the database by sending an `INSERT` statement and read using a `SELECT` statement. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

I personally hate W3Schools, but [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) will get you started on how to insert data into a database.

You should note that `mysql_` functions are being deprecated and you should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Well, so tell the right resource from the start, don't say "look here, but that's not how you should do"

Comment: So they are being deprecated. Can you tell me what the alternative to mysql_ functions are?

Comment: @DamienPirsy You seem quite bitter from your comment above and here.

Comment: @Ckrill Yes. [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: The W3Schools link is getting me somewhere. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You would run sql queries on the database.

This is a simple example of running a select statement on the database (but it won't show anything if you don't have anything inserted into the database)

```
$sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM tablename;
$result = mysql_query($sqlStatement,$db_server);

//this will calculate the number of rows in $result
 $rows=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
//the loop below will extract each row in $result and put it in $variable. 
while ($i < $num) {
   $variable=mysql_result($result,$i,"column_name");
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand what each component of your MAMP server does. If you're getting to the third echo, then none of the previous function calls failed. If you had problems, the die() function would halt execution and display the mysql_error() text.

In order to interact with data, let's assume you create a table named Students with the following structure:

```
StudentID   varchar(9)
FirstName   varchar(30)
LastName    varchar(30)
```

Here's how you might insert a row:

```
<?php
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Students (StudentID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('123456789', 'Michael', 'Hunt')");
   if (!$result) {
      die('query failed: ' . mysql_error());
   }
?>
```

Here's how to retrieve all the rows:

```
<?php
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Students");
   if (!$result) {
      die('query failed: ' . mysql_error());
   }
?>
```

If the retrieval is successful, here's a code snippet to throw your results in a table and display them:

```
<?php
   $numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);
   echo "<table>\n<tr>";
   for ($i=0; $i < $numfields; $i++)
      { echo '<th>'.mysql_field_name($result, $i).'</th>'; }
   echo "</tr>\n";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      { echo '<tr><td>'.implode($row,'</td><td>')."</td></tr>\n"; }
   echo "</table>\n"
?>
```